# How to set different color & size for numbers and characters of a string

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, spannablestring

I receive a dynamic string from a web service and it contains numbers and characters.

**Examples**

`Distance is 5000 mph`

`Arrival in 2 hours & 40 minutes`

---

I want a different **color** - **fontype** - **size** for both the numbers and the charcters. 
I know how to use `Spannable` for a string, but I must know the start and end index for each which I don't because the string is dynamic.!

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions? You could use these to separate the words and numbers

Comment: You should use Spannable to customize part of the string. In your case you want different color and font for number and string ?

Comment: @user8159708 I don't know how to use that, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Ankita I know, but that requires me to know the start and end index for both the numbers part and the string part which I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use the below code to find out all the numbers from your string in an array and by using it you can customize it-

```
private fun getNumbers(string:String){
        val p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(,\\d+)*?\\.?\\d+?")
        val numbers: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        val m: Matcher =
            p.matcher(string)
        while (m.find()) {
            numbers.add(m.group())

        }
        println(numbers)
    }
```

If the string is **Arrival in 2 hours & 40 minutes** then this function will return you - [2,40] as the end result.